# Email Template AEM CQ5 foreach loop

Tags: html-email, aem, email-templates

I need to send an email that lists out product information for multiple products. Is there a way to create a email template with a foreach loop in aem? I have implemented a static email structure where I would replace the string names, for example https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/email-api.html. But I need to loop over data and I am not sure how to do that. Any information or direction on this would be helpful.

Comment: maybe you can share what you have tried and then people would be able to help you.

Answer (score -1):

Samy,

One possible answer could be, having a server side templating. AEM does support multiple templating methods like Sightly, handlerbars etc.

Here is good doc which could help you.
http://labs.6dglobal.com/blog/2014-05-22/sightly-vs-handlebars-vs-jsp-comparing-scripting-languages/

--
Jitendra